# Retry for three times If the File Exists in c#

Tags: asp.net, .net

My Requirement is i want to retry if the specific file exists,suppose like currently i'm doing svn installation / uninstallation so if the svn is installed then it will create RevisionNumber.txt and if the svn is uninstalled then ReveisionNumber.txt is deleted

So My Requirement is if RevisionNumber.txt exists / Svn exists i want to retry the process of svn uninstallation for 3 times.

can anyone please sort me out ? below is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SVNUNINSTALL
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Process()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
            bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(exists);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static void main(String[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your problem?  What have you tried?

Comment: I want to uninstall the file by retrying for 3 times if the file exists

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void Process()
 {
     bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");

     for(int i = 0; i < 3 && exists; i++)
     {    
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
         Sleep(2000); // or long enough to ensure the uninstall process finishes executing
         exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");             
     }
     Console.WriteLine(exists);
     Console.ReadLine();

 }
```

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, Sleep() the thread for a second or two.  If the concern is whether or not the file will be found on another pass, enough time should be allowed for the file's presence to be updated.   If you don't sleep, you're going to check it three times very, very rapidly and possibly miss that state change.

Comment: @user1895086 - good point - code updated to include your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Chambo Thanks A Lot Solved My Problem :)

Comment: Thanks user1895086 Solved My Problem :)

Comment: But Could you help me out by providing the solution through Recursive Methods Please like in recursive methods instead of showing the file exists for two times we can return right And through count ++ can't we loop for 3 times ? Could you please help me out ?

Comment: @ShashankKolpuru - If this answer solved your problem please upvote and mark it as the solution.  If you need assistance with a different solution using recursion please ask a separate question in a new thread.